# Bootstrap Navbar - Border around menu items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: Menu]

I'm trying to apply border around menu items in navbar in bootstrap but it doesn't seem to work as per solution provided elsewhere.

I've following in my custom.css which doesn't work.

```
.navbar-default { border-color: #662D91; }
```

I've tried another way to do it by following code but it has menu jumping issues

```
ul.nav a:hover {
    color: #662D91;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #662D91;
}

.navbar-nav li.active > a {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #662D91;
}
```

How do we add border around menu items in easiest way?

Following is html and custom CSS which gives me border but menu jumps when hover over it.

HTML

```
<ul id="w1" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav">
    <li><a href="/yii/web/site/index">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/yii/web/site/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pdd_yii/web/site/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pdd_yii/web/site/login">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

custom.css

```
a {
    color: #662D91;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav a:hover {
    color: #662D91;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #662D91;
}

.navbar-nav li.active > a {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #662D91;
}
```

Comment: Are you loading your custom.css after bootstrap.css? Are the styles being overridden or don't apply at all?

Comment: I'm loading custom.css after bootstrap.css. I can see custom.css changes are being applied for other elements so it's not an issue with css inclusion order.

Comment: Share your html for the menu and the custom css afecting it.

Comment: Added html and css. With this code I get border but menu jumps when you hover over it.

Comment: What do you mean with jump? Do you want the border every time or just when active?

Comment: Both. When you hover it should be border and when active it should be border. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: No, but I don't see what's the problem then.

Comment: try applying it on ".navbar nav li". does it show when you hover or click at a?

Comment: I've added gif which shows the issue.

Comment: @DaveMS I see that. Just as I suspected. the border applies to hover and active, but not in the li (list item) itself.

Comment: @jmag so how to fix it?

Comment: @DaveMS I inspect the element I need to change to make sure I get the right selector. What you need is remove .active from li.active. Alternately, you want a background color change at .active for a more dramatic effect.

Comment: .navbar-nav li {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #662D91;
}

Comment: This will apply the border to all list item

Comment: Tx, I got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will apply borders to list items.

```
.navbar-nav li {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 2px solid #662D91;
}
```

This will reverse the color for hover and active states.

```
ul.nav a:hover,.navbar-nav li.active > a{
color: #fff;
background-color: #662D91;
border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```